Getting Empty reply from server when curling using Consul - Config entry not found for \"proxy-defaults\" / \"global\"
This question is related to Consul.
I am struggling with Consul for a while to get things working. To summarize I have 1 K8S and 1 Nomad cluster. I also have 1 Consul Server deployed externally of the above clusters. So far I have connected both of these clusters into the Consul Server.
Below are my Consul configurations
Consul Server:
cat /etc/consul.d/consul.hcl
data_dir = "/opt/consul"

client_addr = "0.0.0.0"

ui_config{
  enabled = true
}

server = true

advertise_addr = "192.168.60.10"

bootstrap_expect=1

retry_join = ["192.168.60.10"]

ports {
 grpc = 8502 
}

connect {
 enabled = true
}

Kubernetes: consul-values.yaml
global:
  enabled: false
  tls:
    enabled: false
externalServers:
  enabled: true
  hosts: ["192.168.60.10"]
  httpsPort: 8500
server:
  enabled: false
syncCatalog:
  enabled: true
  toConsul: false
  toK8S: false

Nomad config: nomad.hcl
data_dir  = "/opt/nomad/data"
bind_addr = "0.0.0.0"

server {
  enabled          = true
  bootstrap_expect = 1  
}

advertise {
 http = "192.168.40.10:4646"
 rpc = "192.168.40.10:4647"
 serf = "192.168.40.10:4648"
}

client {
  enabled = false  # Disable the client on the server
}

consul {
 address = "192.168.60.10:8500"
 checks_use_advertise = true
}

Below are my manifest files:
Kubernetes
nginx-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: k8s-nginx
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: k8s-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: k8s-nginx
      annotations:
        'consul.hashicorp.com/connect-inject': 'true'
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: k8s-nginx
        image: nginx:alpine
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - |
          echo "Hello World! Response from Kubernetes!" > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html && nginx -g 'daemon off;'

nginx-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  annotations:
    'consul.hashicorp.com/service-sync': 'true'  # Sync this service with Consul
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: k8s-nginx
pod.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: multitool-pod
  labels:
    app: multitool
spec:
  containers:
  - name: network-multitool
    image: praqma/network-multitool:latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80

NOMAD: nginx.nomad
job "nginx" {
  datacenters = ["dc1"] # Specify your datacenter
  type        = "service"

  group "nginx" {
    count = 1  # Number of instances

    network {
      mode = "bridge" # This uses Docker bridge networking
      port "http" {
        to = 80 
      }
    }

    task "nginx" {
      driver = "docker"

      config {
        image = "nginx:alpine"

        # Entry point to write message into index.html and start nginx
        entrypoint = [
          "/bin/sh", "-c",
          "echo 'Hello World! Response from Nomad!' > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
        ]
      }

      resources {
        cpu    = 500    # CPU units
        memory = 256    # Memory in MB
      }

      service {
        name = "nginx-service"
        port = "http"  # Reference the network port defined above
        tags = ["nginx", "nomad"]

        check {
          type     = "http"
          path     = "/"
          interval = "10s"
          timeout  = "2s"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

K8S pods
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP           NODE                   NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
k8s-nginx-68d85bb657-2tgz7   2/2     Running   0          19h    30.0.1.103   k8s-cluster3-worker1   <none>           <none>
multitool-pod                1/1     Running   0          101m   30.0.1.26

Only k8s-nginx-68d85bb657-2tgz7 has consul sidecar proxy running along it (2/2). Other pods are not a part of service mesh. I am trying to test the load balancing and fail over between K8S and Nomad through Consul. In Consul UI I can see that the services are available as below screenshot.
Link for screenshot: https://i.sstatic.net/trrVjHky.png (because I am not allowed to post images)
Since I am using the same service name for both K8s and Nomad the pods behind it are available inside the same service name (nginx-service)
When I try to curl to the k8s-nginx-68d85bb657-2tgz7 from multitool-pod or from the host I am getting curl: (52) Empty reply from server error. This is the same when I try to curl to the pod's IP or curl nginx-service.
curl http://192.168.60.10:8500/v1/catalog/services | jq
{
  "consul": [],
  "nginx-service": [
    "nginx",
    "nomad"
  ],
  "nginx-service-sidecar-proxy": [],
  "nomad": [
    "http",
    "serf",
    "rpc"
  ],
  "nomad-client": [
    "http"
  ]
}

curl http://192.168.60.10:8500/v1/catalog/service/nginx-service | jq
[
  {
    "ID": "cb3ad82f-ce59-36c7-b1fc-7b5adb672411",
    "Node": "consul-server",
    "Address": "192.168.60.10",
    "Datacenter": "dc1",
    "TaggedAddresses": {
      "lan": "192.168.60.10",
      "lan_ipv4": "192.168.60.10",
      "wan": "192.168.60.10",
      "wan_ipv4": "192.168.60.10"
    },
    "NodeMeta": {
      "consul-network-segment": "",
      "consul-version": "1.19.2"
    },
    "ServiceKind": "",
    "ServiceID": "_nomad-task-5cb09d14-47fa-aacb-368f-50f9b0ca4970-nginx-nginx-service-http",
    "ServiceName": "nginx-service",
    "ServiceTags": [
      "nginx",
      "nomad"
    ],
    "ServiceAddress": "192.168.40.11",
    "ServiceTaggedAddresses": {
      "lan_ipv4": {
        "Address": "192.168.40.11",
        "Port": 20276
      },
      "wan_ipv4": {
        "Address": "192.168.40.11",
        "Port": 20276
      }
    },
    "ServiceWeights": {
      "Passing": 1,
      "Warning": 1
    },
    "ServiceMeta": {
      "external-source": "nomad"
    },
    "ServicePort": 20276,
    "ServiceSocketPath": "",
    "ServiceEnableTagOverride": false,
    "ServiceProxy": {
      "Mode": "",
      "MeshGateway": {},
      "Expose": {}
    },
    "ServiceConnect": {},
    "ServiceLocality": null,
    "CreateIndex": 80705,
    "ModifyIndex": 80705
  },
  {
    "ID": "",
    "Node": "k8s-cluster3-worker1-virtual",
    "Address": "192.168.50.11",
    "Datacenter": "dc1",
    "TaggedAddresses": null,
    "NodeMeta": {
      "synthetic-node": "true"
    },
    "ServiceKind": "",
    "ServiceID": "k8s-nginx-68d85bb657-2tgz7-nginx-service",
    "ServiceName": "nginx-service",
    "ServiceTags": [],
    "ServiceAddress": "30.0.1.103",
    "ServiceTaggedAddresses": {
      "virtual": {
        "Address": "10.107.180.39",
        "Port": 80
      }
    },
    "ServiceWeights": {
      "Passing": 1,
      "Warning": 1
    },
    "ServiceMeta": {
      "k8s-namespace": "default",
      "k8s-service-name": "nginx-service",
      "managed-by": "consul-k8s-endpoints-controller",
      "pod-name": "k8s-nginx-68d85bb657-2tgz7",
      "pod-uid": "330f7c09-fe33-41a3-8d11-ce98d358c873",
      "synthetic-node": "true"
    },
    "ServicePort": 80,
    "ServiceSocketPath": "",
    "ServiceEnableTagOverride": false,
    "ServiceProxy": {
      "Mode": "",
      "MeshGateway": {},
      "Expose": {}
    },
    "ServiceConnect": {},
    "ServiceLocality": null,
    "CreateIndex": 80732,
    "ModifyIndex": 80846
  }
]

When I try to even curl to k8s-pod IP it gives me curl: (52) Empty reply from server
k exec -it multitool-pod -- curl 30.0.1.103
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
command terminated with exit code 52

As per the journalctl -u consul I can see the below error
consul-server consul[36093]: 2024-09-14T21:52:54.635Z [ERROR] agent.http: Request error: method=GET url=/v1/config/proxy-defaults/global?stale= from=54.243.71.191:7224 error="Config entry not found for \"proxy-defaults\" / \"global\""

I assume this can be an issue related to Proxy, but unfortunately I do not get it how to resolve or where to implement it although I tried to refer the docs, hence seeking your kind support.
I also came across upstream, but I am only trying to curl to the service name to see how the requests are routed. I am not developing a frontend or backend services where backend is added as an upstream.
I am stuck with this thing for a while now and therefore seek your kind advice.
Thank you!
